# Magento 2 - Check if Cart Price rule is active for product

Tags: magento2, product, shopping-cart-price-rules

I am exploring the possibilities to show active Cart Price rules on a product page. For example, if I have a blue shirt in the category 'shirts' and I create a Cart Price rule for 20% discount on the category 'shirts', is it possible to check this for a product?

I'm trying to fetch all active cart price rules for a product. In the example of the shirt, I want to show 'Get 20% discount on all shirts' on that specific product page.

I explored the sales-rule module but did not find a possible solution. It should be possible right?

Comment: If this is the your requirement then create catalog price rule, why are you creating cart price rule ???

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala if I create a catalog price rule, the new price is directly shown on catalog pages. I want to show it as a discount in the cart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this fixed by using: `\Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\CollectionFactory $collection`.

I retrieve all rules with:

```
$rules = $this->collection->create();
```

You could also filter this collection on Website and store filter.

After you retrieve the collection you can loop through all rules and check if you could apply the rule for the current product:

```
$product->setProductId($product->getId());

    /** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $rule */
    foreach ($rules as $rule) {
        try {
            if ($rule->getActions()->validate($product)) {
                $activeRules[] = $rule;
            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of Rule module you should look in

```
// Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item    
$item->getAppliedRuleIds()
```

Cart contains items, items hold data about applied rules. From that point you will be able to say what rules are applied to a given item and you can do whatever you wish with that information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see we can get this from a Quote item, but how can I get this for a normal product?

Comment: You can't do that directly. All conditions for cart rules are serialized in conditions_serialized (salesrule table). You can try to deserialize these data and deduce what products if any and under what circumstances will trigger cart discount but that is awkward. Maybe a better solution would be to store that data directly on product.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

```
protected $quoteRepository;
protected $ruleData;

public function __construct(
    ...................................................................
    \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\CustomRuleDataFactory $quoteRepository,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $ruleData,
    ...................................................................
) {
    ...................................................................
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    $this->ruleData = $ruleData;
    ...................................................................
}

public function execute()
{
    $address = 0;
    $quotesVal = 15
    $quotesData = $this->quoteRepository->get($quotesVal);
    $customerId = (int) $quotesData->getCustomerId();
    $productCount = 0;
    foreach ($quotesData->getAllItems() as $quotesDataKey => $quotesDataVal) {
        $address = $quotesDataVal->getAddress();
        $productCount++;
        break;
    }
    if ($productCount) {
        $address->setCachedItemsAll($quotesData->getAllItems());
        $cartRuleData = $this->ruleData->create()->getCollection();
        foreach ($cartRuleData as $ruleKey => $ruleVal) {
            if ($ruleVal->getConditions()->validate($address)){ // if ($ruleVal->getActions()->validate($address))
                echo "Rule Applied";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***